# Using gettext on wp-login.php won't change "Back to site name" text

Tags: wp-login-form

I'm attempting to change the "← Back to sitename" text on the wp-login.php page using gettext but not having much luck.

No matter what I try it doesn't seem to want to work, although I've had success changing the "Lost your password?" text using the same method.

Here is my latest snippet

```
function custom_login_text ( $text ) {

    if (in_array( $GLOBALS['pagenow'], array( 'wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php' ) )) {

        if ($text == '&larr; Back to %s'){$text = 'Test';}
        return $text;

    }

}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'custom_login_text' );
```

I've also tried directly using `← Back to Site Name` but that didn't work either. Am I missing something?

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: So, have you found my answer helpful? I tested on my end and it works. @Syrehn.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet works fine for me.

Although, you should be testing the second argument, rather than the first. [See the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext). You are testing for text that may already have been translated, so your string comparison could fail.

```
    function custom_login_text ( $translated_text, $untranslated_text ) {

        if (in_array( $GLOBALS['pagenow'], array( 'wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php' ) )) {

            if ( '&larr; Back to %s' == $untranslated_text ){
$translated_text = 'Test';
}
            return $translated_text;

        }

    }
    add_filter( 'gettext', 'custom_login_text', 20, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the codex link. :)

I was originally testing my snippet using the [Code Snippets](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plugin and while it was changing the "Lost password" text it wasn't changing the "Back to" text.

I just tossed my original snippet into my theme's functions.php and it's working as intended.

I did test your snippet as well inside my theme's functions.php but it breaks my WP admin (all the text vanishes).  I'll do a bit more playing to follow the codex.

Answer (score 0):

Why not like this:

```
function custom_login_text ( $text ) {

    if (in_array( $GLOBALS['pagenow'], array( 'wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php' ) )) {

        if ($text == '&larr; Back to %s'){$text = 'Test';}
        return $text;

    }

}
add_filter( 'gettext_with_context', 'custom_login_text' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Change text "Back to site name" on wordpress

```
function change_go_to ($text1) {

             if ($text1 == '&larr; Back to %s'){
                 $text1 = 'Go to Website';

             }
                    return $text1;
             }
    add_filter( 'gettext_with_context', 'change_go_to' );
```